# What does it mean the "#" tag in URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, get, tags

can anybody tell me what this tag "#" mean in an URL and how to get it ??
ex :[like here](http://translate.google.ro/#en/ro/hello). I know how to get "?" and "&".

Comment: http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#GeneralURLsyntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Getting it via JavaScript is easy:

```
var fragVal = window.location.hash.substring(1);
alert(fragVal);
```

Getting the fragment identifier using PHP is an issue as the browser won't even send this to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The # part is called the [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) it, identifies a part of a page. Input it in the address bar an the Browser will scroll the identified element into view. In old deprecated HTML versions `<a name="fragmentname">` was used to provided an anchor for a fragment. In current HTML `<div id="fragmentname">` (id attribute of any element) is used.

It is often used in JS to store which status the view currently has, too. On a request browser does not send this part to the server, so you will not receive it in PHP. However it can be used by JS on the page to load additional information using AJAX.